# jersey 2.6 jackson 2.3 and complex keys in maps

Tags: java, json, rest, servlets, jackson

i have a simple Object containing an id. I am searching for a way to use it as a key in a hashmap.

Jersey is registered as a servlet in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.ambientlight.RestConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

jackson is registered here.

```
public class RestConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public RestConfig() {
        packages("org.ambientlight.webservice");
        register(JacksonFeatures.class);
    }
}
```

This is my key object:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SwitchableIdSerializer.class)
public class SwitchableId {

    public String id;

    public SwitchType type;


    public SwitchableId(String id, SwitchType type) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

this is my serializer

```
public class SwitchableIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SwitchableId> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SwitchableId data, JsonGenerator json, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
    JsonGenerationException {
        json.writeString(data.id + "|" + data.type);
    }
}
```

if i return the SwitchableId directly everything works like aspeceted. but if i return a structure with a hasmap then the serializer is not used and just  simple SwitchableId.toString() is applied.

There are so many examples out there. for older releases or if jackson is used standalone. But i cannot find any hint how to deal within a jersey servlet. Please help!

i have tried to annotate the containing class:

```
public class PowerstateHandlerConfiguration extends AbstractActionHandlerConfiguration {

    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = SwitchableIdSerializer.class)
    public Map<SwitchableId, Boolean> powerStateConfiguration = new HashMap<SwitchableId, Boolean>();
}
```

but without success. What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help,

A great annoying thing is. I used that annotation before the map on the server side without success. On my android client instead, a module registration for the spring rest template does not work. And there i use the annotation that you showed me in your answer - and there it works.

Anyway, to answer my question and for everybody who tries to register a module on the object mapper that jersey uses - here is my solution as it works for me now. A Feature is that instead of annotating every map the serializer is always available.

The resource config is the following:

```
public class RestConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public RestConfig() {
        packages("org.ambientlight.webservice");

        register(new ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>() {

            @Override
            public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.registerModule(new SwitchableIdModule());
                return objectMapper;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the serializer was changed to read map keys:

```
public class SwitchableIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SwitchableId> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SwitchableId data, JsonGenerator json, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
    JsonGenerationException {
        json.writeFieldName(data.id + "|" + data.type);
    }
}
```

the serializer is registered in a simple module - that was registered in the ResourceConfig:

```
public class SwitchableIdModule extends SimpleModule {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public SwitchableIdModule() {
        addKeySerializer(SwitchableId.class, new SwitchableIdSerializer());
        addKeyDeserializer(SwitchableId.class, new SwitchableIdDeserializer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Serializer (and deserializer) used for `Map` keys is different from regular value (de)serializer, so annotation to use is:

```
class MapBean {
  @JsonSerialize(keyUsing=SwitchableIdSerializer.class)
  public Map<SwitchableId, String> values;
}
```

and the reason is because write method to use with `@JsonGenerator` is different (`writeFieldName()` instead of `writeString()`).
If using annotations, you need to use this on `Map` property in question. Alternatively you can register key serializers using `SimpleModule`; but for that you need access to `ObjectMapper` that Jersey uses (this is a question for which answer should be found by googling).

Comment: i have tried to annotate the containing class.but without success. If i debug my tomcat 7, the serializer is not called. is there a configuration missing?

Comment: Class to annotate would have to be `Map`, so usually you would annotate property (with `Map` value), not class.

Comment: sorry for that silly question. but could you post an simple example. i don't know if i understand your right